# Censoring license plate in a long video

Tags: editing, post-production

I'm editing a video recorded in a car workshop. The video is about 30 minutes long.

In the background there is a car whose license plate has to be hidden. Unfortunately, the camera moves a lot so it's not possible to censor many frames at a time.

I'm censoring using a mosaic effect over the plate, which has to be added to each frame, but it's taking a very long time.

Can you offer any tips that would help make this process faster?

I'm using Wondershare Filmora 9 for this job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about Filmora 9, but Google Motion Tracking. You just need to roughly track the sign and make a blur bigger than the sign, so it's allways covered. If you want to exactly censor the sign, you need to track the corners. But I'd think filmora can't do that

Answer (score 0):

To make this process faster - you would either need to use KeyFrames or Motion Tracking, but Wondershare Filmora 9 does not support either. There are other free software packages that do support KeyFrames and Motion Tracking like Davinci Resolve.